# Ajquery ajax call results 301 error moved permamently

Tags: jquery, ajax

My setup is a jquery ajax call to a php file. The jquery works IF the php processing time is up to appox ~40 seconds. If the php takes to process longer, the ajax call fails.

jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/path/to/folder/phpfile.php",
    type: "post",

    success: function(data){
        alert("good!"); 
    },
    error:function(xhr,status,error){
        alert("failure");
        console.log(status, error);
    }
});
```

PHP file:

```
set_time_limit(0);  // no time limit is imposed
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
sleep(55); //this will trigger error if >40
echo "1";
exit();
```

.htaccess file:
(this is in order to redirect all www.example.com calls to http://example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have tried:
1) sending 200 ok code at the beginning of the php file
2) I have a set_time_limit(0) at the php file, so it shouldn't time out.
3) I am using a non-permalink as the direct address for the php file

What can cause this behavior and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I managed to solve this problem.

This code works:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 

set_time_limit(0);  // no time limit is imposed

for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
   echo "$i<br>";
   sleep(10);
   ob_flush();
   flush();
};
echo "stop";
exit();
```

So the solution is to add the "header no cache" command at the top of  the file, and add an echo followed by ob_flush (ob referred so php Output Buffers) and flush commands every 10 seconds or so during the execution of the php script.

I hope you will find this solution helpful for you